# Clarification regarding function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, logic

I have been reading Velleman's `How to prove` book and this is one of the paragraphs written in the Functions chapter:

> For every $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, $b = f(a)$ iff $(a,b) \in f$

But shouldn't it be like this:

> For every $a \in A$ and some $b \in B$, $b = f(a)$ iff $(a,b) \in f$

Note the some word in the second sentence which I have framed.

Comment: Haven't seen the book, but I'm guessing Velleman previously defined function $f$ in terms of ordered pairs and, having established its functionality, is introducing the commonly used function notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "some" means "there exists" - "some" is an existential quantifier.  It is very unlikely that you want the sentence

> For every $a$, there is a $b$ such that $b = f(a)$ if and only if $(a,b) \in f$.

This is because we could take any $b$ that is *not* $f(a)$, and it would make that sentence true.  So for example, if both $(a,c_1)$ and $(a,c_2)$ were in $f$, for some $c_1 \not = c_2$, but $(a,c_3)$ is not in $f$, then the above sentence is true, but this $f$ is not a function.

The reason Vellman is writing that sentence is to try to tell you about the $b$'s that *are* values of $f$. It is true that for a function $f$, we have

> For every $a$, for every $b$, $b = f(a)$ if and only if $(a,b) \in f$.

because that is the definition of "$b = f(a)$".

Comment: Is there a need of the condition $(a,c_3) \notin f $ for $f$ to be an invalid function. I think the fact $(a,c_1) \in f$ and $(a,c_2) \in f$ for some $c_1 \neq c_2$, itself leads to the fact that $f$ is not an function. Am i missing something ?

Comment: No, I don't think so. The point of $(a,c_3) \not\in f$ is that we can use $c_3$ as $b$ in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

No, the version in the book is correct. The point is that the set $f$ specifies the function f.

It means that if $(a,b) \in f$ then $f(a) = b$ but also vice versa $f(a) = b \Rightarrow (a,b) \in f$. Furthermore, and I guess that where your confusion comes from, $f(a) \neq b$ then $(a,b) \not \in f$ and vice versa.

Maybe an example helps. $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ where $f(x)= 2*x$ then $f = \{(1,2),(2,4),(3,6),\dots\}$.

I suggest you think about what "A iff B" means. Especially, that "not A iff not B" follows from "A iff B".

Answer (score 0):

Velleman is correct. Just found his book online [here](https://opeconomica.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/daniel-j-velleman-how-to-prove-it.pdf). On page 226, he defines functional relations in terms of ordered pairs. In the next line, he introduces the arrow notation $F: A\to B$.

At the end of page 227, he introduces the $f(a)$ notation for the unique image of $a$ under functional relation $f$.

On page 228, in the section you quote, he introduces the equality $f(a)=b$ for functional relation $f$.